# FastAPI override Depends & Security

Tags: python, dependency-injection, pytest, fastapi

I have a problem with testing endpoints that use both `Depends` AND `Security`. First of all, here is my root endpoint which i can test perfectly fine using `app.dependency_override`:

```
# restapi/main.py
from api_v1.api import router as api_router
from authentication.verification import Verification
from fastapi import FastAPI, Security
from mangum import Mangum

app = FastAPI()
security = Verification()


@app.get("/")
async def root(auth_result: str = Security(security.verify)):
    return {"message": "Hello World this is restapi.py!"}


app.include_router(api_router, prefix="/api/v1")
handler = Mangum(app)
```

And then to test it:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from restapi.main import app, security


def test_root_api():
    client = TestClient(app=app)
    app.dependency_overrides[security.verify] = lambda: ""
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"message": "Hello World this is restapi.py!"}
    app.dependency_overrides = {}


def test_root_api_without_security():
    client = TestClient(app=app)
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 403
    assert response.json() == {"detail": "Not authenticated"}
```

There are no problems when I only use the `Security` function. However I have another endpoint (that i define as `api/v1/exchange_rates` in my api_router) which has both `Depends` and `Security`:

```
# restapi/api_v1/endpoints/exchange_rates.py
security = Verification()
router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/")
async def exchange_rates(
    query: ExchangeRatesQuery = Depends(),
    auth_result: str = Security(security.verify),
):
```

The `ExchangeRatesQuery` is a pydantic BaseModel. The test below for this endpoint works perfectly fine ONLY if I remove the `auth_result: str = Security...` from my endpoint.

```
from restapi.main import app
from restapi.api_v1.endpoints.exchange_rates import security

def test_exchange_rates():
    client = TestClient(app=app)
    app.dependency_overrides[security.verify] = lambda: ""
    response = client.get(
        "/api/v1/exchange-rates?start_date=2023-03-20&end_date=2023-03-21&base_currency=USD&target_currencies=EUR",
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == [
        {
            "exchange_date": "2023-03-20",
            "exchange_rate": "0.88",
            "base_currency": "USD",
            "target_currency": "EUR",
        }
    ]
    app.dependency_overrides = {}
```

Even though I import `security` from my `exchange_rates.py` to ensure that I'm overriding the dependencies of the correct object, this doesn't seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1**
I've also tried patching the verify function with a standard return value of `""` using unittest.mock, but have not been able to make it work that way either.

```
@mock.patch.object(Verification, "verify", lambda: "") # also tried security instead of Verification
def test_exchange_rates()
    ...
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside your `verify` function and in the test; can you verify that the `security` object is the same?

Comment: In debug mode it seems like the `security` objects are different. When my debug mode is in `exchange_rates.py` it was `0x106ca4100`, and when i stepped forward it went into `main.py` which had a security object of `0x106ce4190`. Step forward into `test_exchange_rates.py` and the object was `0x104e94d30`. Seems like at least different objects.

Comment: I have tried importing `security` from `restapi.main` aswell but it doesn't work. (As expected I guess, since i just mentioned they are all different instances)

Comment: I tried doing something similar to this response: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/641#issuecomment-706744052 but I can't seem to get it to work, still getting a `403` response regardless of what path or object i patch (e.g. Verification, security, restapi.authentication.verification.Verification, etc)

Comment: I'd start by finding out _why_ they're different objects, as that seems to indicate that you're not getting the object you thought you were getting when registering the overload.

Comment: Finally got it to work after 2 days by investigating your response more. It seems like i had some circular imports which instantiated the `security` object multiple times. What solved it was transforming my `Verification` class into a Singleton. If you write this as an answer i will give it the green tick, big thanks for engaging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.dependency_overrides` works by using the *actual* function instance as a key - i.e. the exact function instance that gets passed to `Security` or `Depends`.

If these functions are not the same - either because they're registered to different instances or that they're being dynamically generated (for example by returning a function defined inside another function - usually as a closure), the dependency will not be overriden (since FastAPI has no way of knowing what function to replace the other one with).

Make sure they're actually the same instance and same function. If you attach debug breakpoints inside the function / method being called, you should be able to see if they're the same as you expect them to be (for example by looking at `self` or the function being returned).